# Show that any ball in $\mathbb R^n$ is path connected.

Tags: real-analysis

So I was given this question and have been thinking about it for a while but I can't seem to figure out where to go with it exactly. From other answers online people refer to using the fact that $[0,1]$ is convex but I am not familiar with this idea. The other method I have seen is using the fact that intervals in $\mathbb R$, like $[0,1]$, are path connected and then constructing continuous functions to show a given ball in $\mathbb R^n$ is connected as well. If anyone could give a more detailed explanation of this method that would be really appreciated.

Comment: By "any ball", do you mean "for all $n$, the Euclidean balls", or do you mean "for all $n$, for all norms, the balls with respect to the norm"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You should give an example of this "other method", so that someone knows how much more detailed they need to be.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for the links I will be giving them a read soon.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I am going off of the explanation I saw in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284893/how-can-i-prove-that-any-ball-in-mathbbrn-is-connected when I was writing the question.

Comment: @Gae.S. the question is exactly what I have as the title so I believe it is for all n, the Euclidean balls.

Answer (score 5):

If $x$ and $y$ are two points in a ball then $\gamma (t)=tx+(1-t)y$ defines a path from $x$ to $y$ lying in the  ball.

In the case of an open ball $B(x_0,r)$ we have $\|x-x_0\| <r$ and $\|y-x_0\| <r$ implies $$\|tx+(1-t)y-x_0\| =\|tx+(1-t)y-(tx_0+(1-t)x_0)\|$$ $$\leq t \|x-x_0\| +(1-t)\|y-x_0\|<tr+(1-t)r=r$$. The proof is similar for a closed ball.

Comment: I think it's possible to be confused by this. As it stands right now, isn't this a straight line?

Comment: @David If you take two points in  a ball in $\mathbb R^{n}$ the line segment connecting them is inside the ball.

Comment: @KaboMurphy can you show explicitly why the segment is always contained in the ball? I can't seem to get the inequality to be < r

Comment: @Hisham I have added a proof.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be any norm on a real vector spave $V$. Then for all $v_0\in V$ and $r>0$, the ball (with respect to this norm) $B_r(v_0)=\{\,v\in V:\|v-v_0\|<r\,\}$ is path connected.
Indeed, if $v_1,v_2\in B_r(v_0)$, consider $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to V$ given by
$$\gamma(t):=\begin{cases}(1-2t)(v_1-v_0)+v_0&0\le t\le \frac12\\(2t-1)(v_2-v_0)+v_0&\frac12\le t\le 1\end{cases} $$
an verify by short computations that a) $\|\gamma(t)-v_0\|<r$ for all $t\in(0,1]$, and b) $\|\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)\|<2r|t_2-t_1|$. This makes $\gamma$ a continuous map into $B_r(v_0)$, i.e., a path from $v_1$ to $v_2$.